# How to test whether a teabag has polyester fibres or not, without waiting for it to compost?

Tags: composting, materials

Some teabags are made (or partially made) of polyester fibres, and stay intact in compost after everything else has broken down.

Is there a quick way to test whether a teabag contains polyester, as compared to paper (and cotton, when a thread with a tag is attached)?

Are there any other non-biodegradable materials used in teabags, such as nylon?

Comment: it should be pretty evident if you light it on fire. Polyester fibers will melt and drip, cotton and other natural fibers will not.

Comment: @ThatIdiot Not a bad idea... probably best to do it outside, and take care not to breathe the smoke...

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of suggesting something too obvious: contact the manufacturer.

Hats off to Wendy from Moral Fibres for doing some research on this:
http://moralfibres.co.uk/is-there-plastic-in-your-tea/